# JBO-25002: What is the reason for this error?

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper

I was running my project and was checking recently modified module. On click of the Menu tab it was giving me "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" and when I checked in the log I could find the following description:

```
JBO-25002: Definition com.project.view.pageDefs.pages_per_SearchPageDef 
    of type Form Binding Definition not found
oracle.jbo.NoDefException: JBO-25002: Definition com.project.view.pageDefs.pages_per_SearchPageDef 
    of type Form Binding Definition not found
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you were checking "recently modified module".  What modification did you make?  Was it something which invalidated the business component definition?  The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97337_01/ias102_otn/buslog.102/bc4j/jboerrormessages.html#25002) says this about JBO-25002:

> "Provide a correct name for the business component definition. If the
>   definition is not in the classpath, you must include it there. Names
>   are of the format
>   `myProjectPackage.BusinessPackage.BusinessComponent`. This error can
>   also occur if there is a case conflict, as when the database expects
>   "DEPTNO" and receives "Deptno" instead."

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after changing a query in my View Object. The change removed 3 columns but in the PageDef file the tree binding retained the old column names. I manually removed those column names to fix the problem.